# Program in Python

Tags: python, apache-pig

this is the code I have to make a pig-latin translator and I can't seem to get it to translate, anyone have tips to make this work?

I think that my issue is within the encode and starts with vowel parts but I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: in the encode function you only process the first word and then return. You should create an empty list pattern = [] and then call pattern.append(word[1:] + word[0] + 'ar')  or pattern.append(word + 'way') for each word, then return pattern when finished

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adjust these 3 functions:

```
def starts_with_vowel(word):
    # return True if the word starts with a vowel and False otherwise
    return word[0] in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

def encode(word):
    # translate a single word to the secret language
    # call starts with vowel to decide which pattern to follow
    if starts_with_vowel(word):
        return word[1:] + word[0] + 'ar'
    else:
        return word + 'way'

def translate(message):
    # translate the whole text to the secret language
    # call encode to translate individual words in text
    return ' '.join(encode(word) for word in message)
```

the biggest problem was in `encode()` and `starts_with_vowel()` iterating through all words (but your comment says it should work on a *single word*)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot assign in `translate` function:
Must be:

```
phrase = ' '.join(encode(message))
return phrase
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @delimitry's answer, also change the *words* to *word* in the if condition of the second function, i.e, change -

```
if starts_with_vowel(words):
```

to -

```
if starts_with_vowel(word):
```